# Problems with installing Numpy in Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to install the OpenCV library for Pyhton in a Windows 8.1 machine and when I run the line `import cv2` (cv2 is a file from the OpenCV library which requires Numpy to be already installed) in Idle I get the error:

```
**RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x7**
```

I've already istalled the version  9 and the error returned, but I'm not findind an .exe file for the latest version of Numpy which seems to be 1.14

Any help?

Comment: Can you say on which plattform you are? Nevertheless, probably the easiest way to get OpenCV up and running is using Anaconda together with venvs.

Comment: It worked from the similar question's answer, thanks!!

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.5, as required from the OpenCV offcial website's tutorial to install it for Python-Windows.

Comment: But I got the solution from isntalling Pip and updating my Numpy in the command line with "pip install numpy --upgrade" as mentioned in the similar question posted above.